# Cannot send message without a sender address Swift_TransportException

Tags: laravel

****I am using laravel 7. I want to verify email but it doesn't work. It says Swift_TransportException Cannot send message without a sender address****
**1. I cannot find the solution

2.How to solve this problem in laravel 7**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

   Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home')->middleware('verified');
```

**## User model.....I think user model is oky ##**

```
<?php

 namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
 use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

 class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];
```

}

**## .env ##**

```
  MAIL_MAILER=smtp
  MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
  MAIL_PORT=2525
  MAIL_USERNAME=ab9a6ab0949439
  MAIL_PASSWORD=d1fcb35b942504
  MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
  MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
  MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Comment: it seems that 'MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null' should be set to an valid email address

Comment: Here I used mailtrap and If  I used valid gmail in MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS field, is it work?

Comment: Yes providing a valid email address in the MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS will do

Comment: Thanks you all. It works. I  just put valid email in MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably is caused by the null setting `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS`:

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=test@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=YourAppName
```

Please note that when you are using mailtrap you can use any valid email (even if it does not exist). Then check in your mailtrap account https://mailtrap.io/inboxes if you received anything.